# how to subtract date from another date in oracle

Tags: oracle

Let's say I am having a table **orders** and having column

```
LastUpdatedDate, status.
```

What i am trying to do is -

> picks all the Order which are ‘P’ status and lastupdate is two days
>   back from current date

.

can any one help me in writing a query to get my result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select * from yourtable
where status = 'P' 
and LastUpdatedDate < sysdate - 2
```

Comment: +1, but be aware that we're comparing *time* values (to the nearest second), not dates. So this will return rows where the LastUpdatedDate was more than 48 hours ago.